# How to style input elements independently

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I'm styling a specific form field, but the style doesn't seem to apply. I'm using Angular 7.

This is my form:

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <mat-form-field *ngIf="number">
      <input matInput disabled [value]="number">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field *ngIf="name">
      <input name="address" matInput disabled [value]="building.name">
    </mat-form-field>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want the number field to have a width of 200px and the name field to take up the rest of the available space.

CSS file:

```css
.mat-form-field {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  width: 200px;
}

:host ::ng-deep input.mat-input-element[name=address] {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Both fields take up 200px and the name field value is clipped in between. It doesn't expand to the size of the value.

Comment: Both `number` and `name` takes 200px from `mat-form-field` so `address` width is 100% = 200px. Use flex if you don't need to support old browsers ;)

Comment: yes i used and it works

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
:host /deep/{
  input.mat-input-element[name=address] {
   width: 100%;
  }
}
```

or

```
::ng-deep{
   input.mat-input-element[name=address] {
   width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to define your own custom class and set the CSS and use that class:

```
.extra-width {
  // your CSS
  width: 100%;
}
```

and use it in HTML like:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <mat-form-field class="extra-width" *ngIf="number">
            <input matInput disabled [value]=" number ">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field  class="extra-width" *ngIf="name">
            <input name="address" matInput disabled [value]="building.name ">
        </mat-form-field>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below CSS :

```css
ul{
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/******** dont use upper CSS ************/

mat-form-field input {
width: 200px;
display: inline-block;
}
mat-form-field input[name=address] {
width: calc(100% - 220px);
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
  <mat-form-field *ngIf="number">
  <input matInput disabled [value]=" number ">
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field *ngIf="name">
  <input name="address" matInput disabled [value]="building.name ">
  </mat-form-field>
 </li>
</ul>
```